# How do I raise "Uncovering Secrets Framed in Gold"?

Tags: fallen-london

I have **Uncovering Secrets Framed in Gold: 1** and would like to follow this storyline and raise it to 8, in order to unlock a storylet which requires it.

I'm puzzled about how to do that: do I have to wait for the right card or what? I searched for such a frame among my Curiosities but I couldn't find it.

How did I raise it to 1 in the first place, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Uncovering Secrets Framed in Gold** is tracked as a quality, not as an item. Specifically, you can find it under the Intrigue category of qualities on your character page; the non-item qualities are on the bottom-left. You can raise this quality, but it indicates that you've explored the secrets of the painting further, not that you have additional paintings. (That's why it's tracked as a quality rather than as an item. And if I want to get really pedantic, *all* items are treated by the StoryNexus engine that powers Fallen London as Qualities, but that's irrelevant.)

You picked up your first point of USFiG from an opportunity card called [A Bewildering Salon](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/A_bewildering_salon), which is only available once you become a Scholar of the Correspondence. You will gain more of that quality from opportunity cards. This storyline is, unfortunately, one that costs a little money to complete; the [wiki](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/Gold_frame,_black_painting) says it takes 19 Fate/Nex. (I believe that's either *all of* or *more than* the amount of Fate you can pick up normally in the course of playing the game.) As with all storylets that cost Fate/Nex, it rewards you much better than storylets that don't cost Fate/Nex.

This particular storylet occurs entirely in opportunity cards; at every stage, the next step is to wait for another opportunity card. Yes, this takes a while. (My current USFiG quality, now that I've completed the storyline, is at 55, but that's misleading because USFiG occasionally jumps upward by a large amount when you take certain actions. I'm fairly certain there are multiple end-points of the story, with different values of USFiG.)

Comment: Very detailed. For the record, yes I found it under Intrigue, I just kept searching elsewhere since I didn't know what I was searching for.